# Understanding d3.js Box Plot Example (Tickformat & Positioning)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am still in the progress of learning d3.js and right now I am trying to implement a slightly modified version of the Box Plot example from the d3 website:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502

I am struggeling to understand how this particular section of the box.js is working:

```
// Compute the tick format.
  var format = tickFormat || x1.tickFormat(8);

...

boxTick.enter().text(format);
```

First of all, why is this working? As far as I understand this, *format* is just containg a function, how does d3 know to place the integers instead?

Furthermore, I tried to alter the format, since in the example the values are only shown as whole numbers, but I have floats. I digged through the API and found this:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format

So, I tried to use

```
x1.tickFormat(d3.format(".3r"))
```

But it's not working. It just shows the full (and really long) floating numbers now.

One last thing I couldn't figure out so far is, how the size, positioning and spacing of the boxes is calculated?

Thank you for your time and I hope these questions are not too basic!

Comment: What you pass to `.tickFormat()` is a function that will in turn be passed the data for the ticks and format them into the labels.

Comment: I see. So how can I format the labels correctly? (e.g. 0.345678 => 0.35)

Comment: Your format function works fine for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/5q9PT/

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff! It works in your basic example, of course. However, it does not seem to work if you apply it to the .tickFormat() function. I tried to create a fiddle for that, but I cannot get it to run at all...

Answer (score 0):

I just fought through this same confusion and think I understand things a bit better now. To answer your specific question, you can use

```
var format = tickFormat || d3.format(".3r");
```

to manually specify the formatting you want.

As to what `tickFormat()` is actually doing, here's my best guess:

tickFormat calls the function `d3_scale_linearTickFormat()` internally, which is defined [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/scale/linear.js). My interpretation of that function is that the argument is the (hypothetical) number of ticks on the axis, and the return value is a format function which rounds to a sensible number of decimal places.

In the example case (`x1.tickFormat(8)`), you're requesting 8 ticks. I believe the range is taken from the values in the boxplot, which are about 600 to 1000 in the example, so the step size between a set of 8 ticks would be about 50. As a result, rounding the tick values to the nearest integer is a sensible format, which is what is done.

If you instead use `x1.tickFormat(100000)` (give it a try), you're requesting 100000 ticks across a range of 400, so the step between ticks is about 0.004. As a result, d3 decides that 3 points after the decimal is a reasonable number to display for individual ticks (because if it rounded to the integers, many neighboring ticks would be formatted identically). Of course 100000 is an absurd number of ticks in almost any circumstance, but it clarifies what's happening.

And to make things even more confusing, you can call the function with a format string as the second argument like `x1.tickFormat(8, ",.3r")`, in which case it seems to basically ignore the first argument and just use the specified format string.